# getElementbyId() is not working for certain text box type

Tags: javascript, html, templates, notepad

Hi I'm trying to create templates in notepad that I can copy and paste into the console to autofill webforms for work to reduce input time. I am purely using getElementByID().value, however it does not work for a certain type of textbox.

[Image of Textbox type](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMRiv.jpg)

Here is the code for when I inspect the element:

```
<body class="ms-formbody" scroll="yes" style="margin: 0px; border: currentColor; background-color: white;" contenteditable="true" RestrictedMode="true" BaseElementID="Full_x0020_description_x0020_of__9345dd13-8d85-4a88-8fcd-a90356258f96_$TextField" WebLocale="1033"><div></div></body>
```

So `document.getElementById("Full_x0020_description_x0020_of__9345dd13-8d85-4a88-8fcd-a90356258f96_$TextField").value = "example";`

is not working when pasting into the console to try and autofill in.

Any ideas?

Comment: add `id` like `<body class="ms-formbody" id="test" ....`

Comment: `.value` only works on inputs and also your you have no element with that id - instead you seem to have set a BaseElementID attribute

Comment: it is not an `id` in HTML...

Comment: Since there is only one `body` element in a document, just use `document.body` to reference it.

Answer (score 0):

Try in **javascript**

```
document.querySelector('[attribute_name="attribute_value"]');
```

```js
var elements = document.querySelector('[BaseElementID="Full_x0020_description_x0020_of__9345dd13-8d85-4a88-8fcd-a90356258f96_$TextField"]');
elements.textContent="example";
```

```html
<body class="ms-formbody" scroll="yes" style="margin: 0px; border: currentColor; background-color: white;" contenteditable="true" RestrictedMode="true" BaseElementID="Full_x0020_description_x0020_of__9345dd13-8d85-4a88-8fcd-a90356258f96_$TextField" WebLocale="1033"><div></div></body>
```

Try in **jquery** to get element by attribute.

```
$('[attribute_name="attribute_value"]')
```

```js
$('[BaseElementID="Full_x0020_description_x0020_of__9345dd13-8d85-4a88-8fcd-a90356258f96_$TextField"]').text("example");
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body class="ms-formbody" scroll="yes" style="margin: 0px; border: currentColor; background-color: white;" contenteditable="true" RestrictedMode="true" BaseElementID="Full_x0020_description_x0020_of__9345dd13-8d85-4a88-8fcd-a90356258f96_$TextField" WebLocale="1033"><div></div></body>
```

Comment: The question was not tagged with JQuery and all that's really needed here is `document.body`.

Comment: I added answer in both javascript and jqurey please try this :) @Michael Grey